# SoftAssert - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.collections.Maps.newLinkedHashMap()

Tags: java, hashmap, assert, assertions

I would like to use SoftAssert in the test.
But when I try to compile project (Java 8 and also try with java 7 under IntelliJ 2016.2, org.testng with 6.10) I get:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.testng.collections.Maps.newLinkedHashMap()Ljava/util/Map;
```

All that I added in my code:

```
SoftAssert softAssert = new SoftAssert();
```

In test:

```
softAssert.assertFalse(...)
softAssert.assertAll();
```

I don't have any option what I should change... because in theory, it's so simple

Comment: What's your project setup? Are you using maven / ant / just java?

Comment: My project is a Maven project, but my tests are written in Java

Comment: Can you paste the image of your package explorer - there's some setup issue for sure.  Also the image of your buildpath.

Comment: @niharika_neo I reply below

Answer (score 0):

Download below jar and add to your build path.

[TestNg jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.9.4)

Hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Where my main pom contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>…</groupId>
    <artifactId>f-…-filesystem</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>f-… -component</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        …
    </properties>

    <repositories>
            …    
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>            
               …
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

f-…-component is a package in main project f-…-filesystem

As a 'working directory' I use full path: C:\Users...\IdeaProjects\f-...-filesystem\f-...-component

And as 'classpath of module' my f-...-component module